# Layout problem with pivot control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Pivot, nothing in the slightest bit unusual and the listbox displays at the top left as I'd expect:

```
    <c:Pivot
      Title="QUESTIONNAIRE"
      ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">

      <c:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding HeaderText}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </c:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

      <c:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>
              <TextBlock>ListboxItemText</TextBlock>
            </ListBoxItem>
          </ListBox> 
        </DataTemplate>
      </c:Pivot.ItemTemplate>

    </c:Pivot>
  </Grid>
```

but when I split this out to use a DataTemplate in Application.Resources, the listbox is centered, vertically and horizontally. How do I get it back to the top left?

```
  <DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplateSample">
      <ListBox
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource styleSelect}"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding Value}">
        <ListBoxItem>
          <TextBlock>ListboxItemText</TextBlock>
        </ListBoxItem>
      </ListBox>
  </DataTemplate>
```

```
    <c:Pivot
      Title="QUESTIONNAIRE"
      ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">

      <c:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding HeaderText}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </c:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

      <c:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <app:PivotDataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" />
      </c:Pivot.ItemTemplate>

    </c:Pivot>

  </Grid>
```

I think I must be missing something obvious!

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating the `ListBox` control itself, specify the explicit height and width and put it inside a `StackPanel`, for example.

Something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplateSample">
  <StackPanel>
      <ListBox
        Height="480" Width="400"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource styleSelect}"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding Value}">
        <ListBoxItem>
          <TextBlock>ListboxItemText</TextBlock>
        </ListBoxItem>
      </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Yes, that does work, though not exactly in the spirit of dynamic layout!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Left` and `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Top` on the `Pivot`.